# Deleting Unnecessary files from a directory using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I want to delete the automatically generated `.crc` files from a particular directory. Here is my code:

```
val existingSparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val fs = FileSystem.get(existingSparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.delete(new Path(s"./src/path/*.crc"), true)
```

But this doesn't delete any `.crc` files as expected. Is there a way to delete these files using scala and spark?

Comment: Do you want to delete them, or do you just not want them to be generated in the first place?

Comment: I don't think `delete` works with wildcards. You need to first use `globStatus` to match all files with the same pattern on HDFS and then run a foreach over that collection and call `fs.delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the wildcard in the Path, `fs.delete` does not work propertly. One possible solution can be trying hadoop `globStatus` like the following:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus
val allStatus = fs.globStatus(new Path("/src/path/*.crc"))
for (currentStatus <- allStatus ) {
    fs.delete(currentStatus.getPath, true);
}
```